# Induction Oven mosfets overheating

Tags: heat, induction, zvs

I made this circuit inspired by this website: http://www.electroboom.com/
[image]

It seemed to work for a few seconds but the mosfets got really hot, they started to smoke and eventually one of them died. I suspect my DC switching power supply might not have a clean voltage signal and this is what is causing the excessive heating.

I'm waiting for a new mosfet and I'm going to try with a battery next time. In the meanwhile, do you have any observations or do you see any other problems that might be causing this? I'm using heat dissipators with thermal grease, but no ventilation.

Comment: you are building stuff from a website that has `boom` in its name?

Comment: @jsotola It is where you learn all the things not to do. The surviving viewers will then have learned what to do in electronics by a process of elimination. ;)

Comment: I doubt a "clean voltage signal" had anything to do with it. As long as you had enough decoupling on the supply. (Also, what happened to the zener diodes clamping the gate voltage on the original circuit? They might have been important)

Comment: I suggest putting it together as recommended in the website (i.e., with the zeners and pull-down resistors on the FET gates).  Then report back.

Comment: Ok, I`ll get the zenners and the resistors too and tell you what happens. Let`s hope for the best!